# Scala <console>:1: error: ';' expected but '(' found

Tags: scala

I keep getting this error when writing a simple recursive function in Scala. What am I missing?

```
scala> def count(n1:Int, n1:Int) : List[Int] = (n1 < n2) ? List() : List(n1, count((n1 - 1), n2))
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but '(' found.
   def count(n1:Int, n1:Int) : List[Int] = (n1 < n2) ? List() : List(n1, count((n1 - 1), n2))
```

Comment: you probably want your else clause to be `n1 :: count((n1 - 1), n2)`

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238184/why-not-provide-an-operator-in-scala

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Scala the ternary operator is `if`. So, `?` and `:` can be replaced with the usual `if` and `else` keywords.

Also, where is `n2` defined? I'll guess in `count`like this `def count(n1:Int, n2:Int) : List[Int] = ...`

Comment: The n2 is just a typo. I changed the operator to `if` and now I'm getting another error.

`
<console>:1: error: illegal start of simple expression
       def count (n1:Int, n2:Int) : List[Int] = def count (n1:Int, n2:Int) : List[Int] = if (n1 < n2) List() else n1 :: count(n1 - 1, n2)
                                                ^
`

Comment: The code in your comment has `def count (n1:Int, n2:Int) : List[Int] =` defined twice.

Answer (score 1):

This works!

`def count(n1:Int, n2:Int) : List[Int] = if (n1 < n2)  List() else n1 :: count((n1 - 1), n2))`

change `count(n1:Int, n1:Int)` to `count(n1:Int,n2)` The rest is adding an `if else` clause instead of the ternary oprator.

A similar code for doing this would be `def count(n1:Int, n2:Int) = (n1 to n2).reverse`

Comment: Thanks replaced it with the `if else` and it worked, thought this was supported on scala

Comment: Since `if else` works and returns, "there's no need" for the ternary operator.